# Magento - SQL command to set "exclude" on product images

Tags: sql, magento

I'm wondering if there's some SQL command I can run that will set any product with only 1 image to "exclude" that image from the image gallery. Adding the following will set all excludes to 1 (or tick the "exclude" image box in other words):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
SET disabled = 1
```

But I need to only do that for products with 1 image, and leave any products with more than 1 image "un-excluded" (or "disabled = 0").

Magento version is 1.4.2.0.

Cheers

UPDATE: I found the following which is doing something similar, although I would want just products with only 1 image to be excluded:

-- Set all images as enabled ("exclude" deselected)

```
update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set disabled = 0;
```

-- Set all the main images as disabled ("exclude" selected) so that they do not show up in “More Views”

```
update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set disabled=1 where value_id in (select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where value in (select value
from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id=(select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code=’image’ and entity_type_id=4)))
```

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your tables?

Comment: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (`value_id`,`store_id`,`label`,`position`,`disabled`)
VALUES
 (18, 0, 'Image', 0, 0); Thing is, I can't find which table specifies whether a product has more than one image. Doesn't seem to be this table.

Comment: The images themselves are stored in the **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery** table.

Comment: We need the structure of your tables to answer you.

Comment: Please also supply the exact version of your Magento, as the tables are specified dynamically the slightest change can affect the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this seems to do the trick:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET disabled = 0; 
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
(SELECT entity_id, COUNT(*) as image_count, MAX(value_id) AS value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg
GROUP BY entity_id
HAVING image_count = 1) AS mg
SET mgv.disabled = 1
WHERE mgv.value_id = mg.value_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than running this as SQL, I would recommend that you change your theme's `template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` file so that it only shows the gallery if there is more than one image (I assume that's what you are trying to achieve??).  Change the line below from `0` to `1`

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
```

The advantage in doing it this way is that you won't need to re-run the SQL every time that you add a new product.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks but I'm specifically looking for an SQL solution.